# How can I select multiple columns while using "when" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the syntax I wanted to use for "loan amount" column. I am creating a data set on ssas for reporting. But I am having a problem adding "loan id" column based on the syntax since I need both "loan amount" and "loan ID" in the same data set. How can integrate "LOAN ID" while keeping the syntax below for "loan amount"?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE    
        WHEN [LoanAmount] <= 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k'
        WHEN [LoanAmount] BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k'
        WHEN [LoanAmount] > 200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
    END [LoanAmount]
FROM
    [dbo].[dim loan detail]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the whole query (entire select). Also, what exactly is the problem? are you getting an error? If so please provide it too.

Comment: the problem is i want to add a column called " loan id" since i want both loan ID and "loan amount" on the data set and i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to add LOAN_ID, you just separate each column with a comma after the SELECT and before the FROM. Also, in this case the "DISTINCT" keyword is not necessary since every LOAN_ID will be unique, and therefore distinct.

```
SELECT
LOAN_ID,
CASE    
WHEN [LoanAmount] <= 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k'
WHEN [LoanAmount] between 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k'
WHEN [LoanAmount] > 200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
END [LoanAmount]
FROM [dbo].[dim loan detail]
```

Comment: idk why it didnt work for me when i did it at first..i deleted distinct and tried and it worked thank you